# How to ensure that there are no duplicates words anywhere in a large text/csv file?

Tags: mysql, regex, notepad++

EDIT. SOLUTION: I ended up creating the joining table in mysql and using mysql statements as this matched the entire string and not partials. I used regex in notepad++ to create the statements for all 1800+ entries. eg:
UPDATE my_table SET city_id = "747" WHERE city_id = "City Name";

---

I have a text file with 1800+ lines of city names and I need to process this file to replace the city names with an numerical value to be used as primary key for a joining table in a database. I have a working power shell script that can do this but there are tons of duplicate words causing problems.

My problem is the city names that contain the same word like this 'Francisco' example:

```
CITY = ID
Francisco = 11
San Francisco = 25
South San Francisco = 35
Franciscoville = 99
```

what I want to achieve is this:

```
CITY = ID
11 = 11
25 = 25
35 = 35
99 = 99
```

What I get is this (fyi: it doesn't seem to matter what order I put things in the lookup table of the PS script):

```
CITY = ID
11 = 11
San 11 = 25
South San 11 = 35
11ville = 99
```

What I'd like to do is extract all of the words like the 'Francisco' example (ie: the shortest string that contains the duplicate) and get those into a separate txt file.

Also, if you look at the example I'd actually have to run this a couple of times. Once I get the 'Francisco' row into a separate text file I now have have a new duplicate problem with "San Francisco" also appearing in the row containing "South San Francisco".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I hope I've made the problem clear enough to understand.

Edit: I should note that I do not know how many or what the duplicates actually are, I just know that there are a lot. What I'm trying to achieve is to both find what the duplicates are and then deal with them.

Comment: Are you restricted to using regex for this task? Why not think in an iterative approach in which you run your file against a "definitions" file where you will input new words like "san", "ville", "ton", "town", "berg", "new", "old", "south", "west", etc... This file will contain stop words for city names and will have a replacement value. The idea is to separate these stop words from proper nouns like "Francisco", "York" or other. Run your program to identify proper and stop words until there are none left. I think regex is not the proper tool for your problem.

Comment: What was wrong with `PRIMARY KEY(city)`?

Answer (score 0):

Am trying to come up with a general solution to for your replace operation.

Suppose you have word **Francisco** in multiple lines and want to assign them different IDs. Here is the regex for the same.

**Regex:** `.*Francisco.*( = (\d*))`

**Explanation:**

- This will match the line with word `Francisco` in it followed by the `ID`.

**Replacement to do:** `\2\1`

- `\2` is the captured `ID`.
- `\1` is part `= ID`.

### <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK6iA0/1)**</kbd>

Comment: My main problem is that I do not actually know what the duplicates are, I just know that there are many.

Comment: Yes and this regex will take care of that even if you don't know. I hope the format of each line is `CITY = ID` and not changed. You can test this regex on a copy of your file.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the words, you need to do the replacements in order from longest strings to shortest strings.  This will eliminate your issue, assuming no replacement string is also a search string (i.e. Apple -> Ball, Ball -> Car)

For your example data, it would mean replacing in the following order:

1. South San Francisco
2. Franciscoville
3. San Francisco
4. Francisco

Comment: This was the first thing that I tried, unfortunately it does not seem to matter what order the rows are in in my lookup table.